# Mac has wrong keyboard layout

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a Mac mini with Snow Leopard installed. It have a blue tooth keyboard. This keyboard is a Swiss-German keyboard with all the necessary special characters on it. I have two problems with this keyboard:

1. No matter what I do, it always acts as an US keyboard. The layout is wrong, <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> are swapped and a lot of other characters are wrong placed. If I show the keyboard layout, it has an US in the title bar.
2. If I try to configure the key board I click on "Configure blue tooth keyboard" in the keyboard configuration. The Mac never finds the keyboard although I can use it (with the wrong layout)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the correct layout in *Language & Text » Input Sources* in *System Preferences*, then selecting it in the Input menu (the one showing the flag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on what Daniel Beck said in the comments, in *System Preferences (language and text -> input sources)* you tell OS X what your keyboard layout is (what keys yield what characters).

For example, I have mine set to french in this screenshot, and when I type, instead of "qwerty" it's "azerty." I think this is what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: At least provide some additional value in the answer ;)

Comment: Ah, I thought the picture was value enough.

Comment: There's an important note to this: As you can see from http://superuser.com/questions/338632/wrong-keyboard-layout-for-login-screen/338745#338745 you have to set the keyboard layout for the login screen in a second step.

Comment: @BetaRide That's only for the login screen - maybe not everyone wants to login with a german keyboard. But you're right, that's another thing to change if needed.

Comment: To change the login language, you have to re-run the setup assistant.  To do so, log in as an admin user and run (from the terminal): sudo rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone; sudo "/System/Library/CoreServices/Setup Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Setup Assistant"