# Wrong keyboard layout for login screen

Tags: mac, login, keyboard-layout

On my Mac mini with Snow Leopard installed, I have a swiss german bluetooth keyboard. This works as expected. However on the login screen the keyboard layout seams to be switched to US.

The keyboard was set to an US layout before by accident. I followed this answer [Mac has wrong keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/questions/334397/mac-has-wrong-keyboard-layout?answertab=votes#tab-top) to set it to the correct swiss german layout. But it seams that this settings are not taken into account on the login screen.

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Lion:

[image]

Snow Leopard:

[image]

Comment: There's nothing I can click on on my login screen. The dropdown of the Snow Leopard screen shot is missing on my machine. How can I make this show up?

Comment: I have 10.6.8 .

Comment: I forgot there was a setting for it: *Users & Groups* / *Accounts* → *☑ Show input menu in login window*. Edited the answer.